# Создания "Шапки" на странице "Каталог" в Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток.Подскажите в каком файле нужно добавить блок(div).
Чтобы обернуть 3 элемента(заголовк,параграф и форму) на главной странице.Нужно сделать белый фон.На скриншоте я выделил его черным цветом.
Сейчас код состоит так

```
<div id="main" class="col-left"> 
<h1 class="page-title">Каталог</h1>
<div class="woof_products_top_panel" style="display: none;"></div>
<p class="woocommerce-result-count">Отображаются все 4 результата</p>
<form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
<select name="orderby" class="orderby">
<option value="menu_order" selected="selected">Исходная сортировка</option>
<option value="popularity">По популярности</option>
<option value="date">По новизне</option>
<option value="price">Цены: по возрастанию</option>
<option value="price-desc">Цены: по убыванию</option>
</select>
</form>
<ul class="products"> </ul>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее благодарю за ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала в директории вашей темы `"Mystile"` создайте директории `\wp-content\themes\mystile\woocommerce\loop\`

1. копируем шаблон `archive-product.php` из `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\` в `\wp-content\themes\mystile\woocommerce\`
2. копируем шаблон `orderby.php` из `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\loop\` в `\wp-content\themes\mystile\woocommerce\loop\`

Теперь редактируем созданные нами файлы:

*archive-product.php*

перед:

```
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
     <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

открываем наш `<div class="page-title-wrap">`

```
    <!-- Start Page Title Wrap-->
    <div class="page-title-wrap">
     <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
      <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

*orderby.php*

после:

```
     <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
      <select name="orderby" class="orderby">
       <?php foreach ( $catalog_orderby_options as $id => $name ) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" <?php selected( $orderby, $id ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $name ); ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     </select>
     <?php
      // Keep query string vars intact
      foreach ( $_GET as $key => $val ) {
       if ( 'orderby' === $key || 'submit' === $key ) {
        continue;
       }
       if ( is_array( $val ) ) {
        foreach( $val as $innerVal ) {
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr( $innerVal ) . '" />';
        }
       } else {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $val ) . '" />';
       }
      }
     ?>
     </form>
```

закрываем наш `</div>`

```
     <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
      <select name="orderby" class="orderby">
       <?php foreach ( $catalog_orderby_options as $id => $name ) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" <?php selected( $orderby, $id ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $name ); ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     </select>
     <?php
      // Keep query string vars intact
      foreach ( $_GET as $key => $val ) {
       if ( 'orderby' === $key || 'submit' === $key ) {
        continue;
       }
       if ( is_array( $val ) ) {
        foreach( $val as $innerVal ) {
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr( $innerVal ) . '" />';
        }
       } else {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $val ) . '" />';
       }
      }
     ?>
     </form>
    </div><!-- End Page Title Wrap-->
```

Таким образом после обновления плагина Woocommerce ваши изменения останутся

Comment: Да,благодарю за ответ,так тоже можно сделать,но я сделал,как написал человек снизу,но Ваш способ тоже подходит,благодарю еще раз :)

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь в 1 случае если вы обновите тему у вас слетят настройки т.к.:

Comment: \wp-content\themes\mystile\includes\theme-woocommerce.php относится к файлам темы

Comment: Да,уже исправил,благодарю."Шапка" появляется и в карточке товара,а через Ваш способ только на странице "Каталог",благодарю :)

Answer (score -1):

У вас установлена тема mystile от WooCommerce.

Код вывода div id="main" находится в файле \wp-content\themes\mystile\includes\theme-woocommerce.php
В этом файле после `<div id="main" class="col-left">` добавьте `<div id="my_header">`

В файле \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\loop\orderby.php перед </div>

Comment: #main Это часть страницы с товарами,если сделать белый фон,то на всю страницу,мне нужна только часть,поэтому нужно добавить див в код страницы,а где этот файл в ВП лежит,я не знаю

Comment: приведенный выше css ставит белый фон только на div id="main", но никак не на всю страницу. Если приведенный код правильный, то белым будет только этот div.

<form... выводится из файла \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\loop\orderby.php 

он вызывается из функции woocommerce_catalog_ordering в файле \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php 

div woof... выводится из плагина woof для woocommerce

div id="main" скорее всего, из темы (обычно есть шаблоны для woocommerce). В самом плагине такого нет.

Но все это не нужно. Покажите страницу, дам css.

Comment: Вот сам сайт http://tiarsekj.bget.ru/shop/
Если #main сделать bg белый будет вот так http://s018.radikal.ru/i527/1610/a3/4bdb408c825f.png

Comment: да, код приведен неполностью, потому совет не работает. Исправляю ответ.

Comment: Да,спасибо за ответ,но я немного не пойму,добавил я в файле  \wp-content\themes\mystile\includes\theme-woocommerce.php новый див,сразу же его закрыл.Но на странице "каталог" поменялась расстановка блоков,а именно подвал уехал в левую сторону,а фильтры в подвал.Как это можно исправить?
Так же не понял в файле \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\loop\orderby.php перед </div>
но в этом файле нету вообще блоков div
Скрин сайта - http://itmag.es/2KSPf
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что div надо открыть в одном файле, а закрыть совсем в другом.

Comment: Да,все благодарю.выставил высоту 110px  и фон белый,но все колонки сбились на моб.версии,не подскажите как восстановить?Заранее благодарю за ответ.
Скрины сайта на моб.экране.
http://s018.radikal.ru/i523/1610/3e/1a7c6302ffb6.jpg

Comment: UPD
padding-top помог,спасибо еще раз :)